# WKWebView open URL on local notification tap

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have PHP web server that sends data messages through firebase to my iOS  WKWebView application and i need to open link received with data message in that WKWebView.

I already have set properly developer account, firebase and iOS application so i am receiving remote notifications like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let body = userInfo["body"] as! String;
    let title = userInfo["title"] as! String;

    if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background)
    {
        localUserNotification(title: title, body: body);
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

than because my push notification is actually a data message, i need to construct, and i am constructing my local notification.

```
func localUserNotification(title: String, body: String){

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound];
    center.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
        (granted, error) in
        if !granted {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.userInfo = ["link": "https://google.com"];
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.1,
                                                    repeats: false)


    let identifier = "UYLLocalNotification"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request);
}
```

because `link` is not valid parameter of `UNMutableNotificationContent` i am passing it in `userInfo` object, at this moment i have working code that shows me local notification when i am receiving data message from my server via firebase, now i need to handle user tapping of this notification what i am trying to do with this method

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background)
    {
        print(response);
    }


    completionHandler();
}
```

but response have no data about `userInfo` sent in local notification, all i see is

```
<UNNotificationResponse: 0x1c42250e0; actionIdentifier: com.apple.UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier, notification:     
<UNNotification: 0x1c42259a0; date: 2018-03-07 11:30:47 +0000, request:     
<UNNotificationRequest: 0x1c403b220; identifier: UYLLocalNotification, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x1c4112a20; title: This is magic, subtitle: (null), body: Well hello there mister, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , peopleIdentifiers: (
), threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
), badge: (null), sound: <UNNotificationSound: 0x1c40bbd80>, hasDefaultAction: YES, defaultActionTitle: (null), shouldAddToNotificationsList: YES, shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground: NO, shouldLockDevice: NO, shouldPauseMedia: NO, isSnoozeable: NO, fromSnooze: NO, darwinNotificationName: (null), darwinSnoozedNotificationName: (null), trigger: <UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger: 0x1c42218c0; repeats: NO, timeInterval: 0.100000>>>>
```

how i can access my link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
```

Comment: It works, despite you can't see userInfo while printing whole response to console, if you try to access userInfo directly, it works,  thank you, i ll accept an answer as soon as possible

Comment: when you print the request it will print the information of request object and not its content.