# Opening link from local notification in WKWebView produces fatal because of Optional unwrapping

Tags: swift

I am trying to open a link sent in my local notification `userInfo` in my WKWebView, i already tried several different options of casting Optional to String, but still no luck, i even tried to check typeof variable i am passing, to be sure it's not Optional anymore, but webView.load still produces fatal, this is my final variant, minimized as much as possible to help reproduce whole situation

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {



    if let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? Dictionary<String,String> {
        if let link = userInfo["link"] {
            let url = URL(string: link)!

            print(type(of: url));
            print(url);

            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url);
            ViewController().webView.load(urlRequest)
        }
    }

    completionHandler();
}
```

still

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` from `ViewController().webView.load(urlRequest)` link is just `https://google.com`

output to console from print is

```
URL // typeof url
https://google.com // url
```

Comment: what is this: `ViewController().webView.load(urlRequest)`?

Comment: This is Swift, it's unnecessary to use semicolons at the end of lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a new `ViewController` after receiving a notification. If this is intended, this is not the right way to create a new `ViewController` (you need to instantiate it from a `storyboard` or a `xib` file and then present it in some way). In your case you're simply creating a new instance of the `ViewController` class without the associated `view`, so your application is most likely crashing because the `webView` property is nil.

If this is not indented and your `ViewController` is already presented on the screen in some way, you need to pass this dictionary to the already existing `ViewController` and this `ViewController` should then open your link. I suggest using [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) for this.

Comment: Thank you, i ll try to use `storyboard` variant, and will post results later, if you interested, here is a bit more about my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151071/wkwebview-open-url-on-local-notification-tap/49151308?noredirect=1#comment85306865_49151308

Comment: Remember to present it on the screen, creating an instance from a storyboard will do nothing by itself.